# passing object from servlet to jsp and getting output with jstl

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am expirementing with jstl.
I place an object (bean) onto req in my servlet as follows:

```
req.setAttribute("myBean", myBean);
```

In my jsp I had:

```
MyBean mb = (MyBean)request.getAttribute("myBean");
<%= mb.getStuff() %>
```

Then I tried to use Jstl as follows:

```
<c:out value="${mb.getStuff}"/>
```

And I get the literal ${mb.getstuff} in the output. 
It is wrong. How should it be.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Tomcat 6.
Eclipse.

This is from sample on web:

```
request.setAttribute("name", "ss ss");
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);

<h3>An Example of c:out JSTL...</h3><br/>
The value comes from servlet is : <b> <c:out value="${name}"/></b>
```

Evaluates to blank.

Comment: Your container isn't evaluating JSP EL. What's your servlet level in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Your eval is correct. I tried a simple string attribute with no luck. I am using tomcat 6. S/B servlet level 2.5. The web.xml, from what I have read, does not need to be modified on Tomcat. Only the jar files need to be placed in WEB-INF/lib. I am using Eclipse and deploying contexts.

Comment: What is the servlet level declared in your `web.xml`?

Comment: Not certain what is being asked, however:
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
'-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN'
  'http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd'>
<web-app>

I changed it to this:
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

Still no good.

Comment: Rebooted tomcat. It is evaluating now to blank. I will update question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (potentially three) issues.

**1.** The servlet level declared in your `web.xml` should be at 2.5+

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

**2.** Request attributes aren't the same as scriptlet variables; the scriptlet variable you've created is invisible to JSP EL, which access scoped attributes, not scriptlet vars. The correct EL would be:

```
${myBean.getStuff}
```

**3.** If `getStuff` is actually a method `getStuff()` then the EL would actually be:

```
${myBean.stuff}
```

Also, make sure the app was redeployed, and the changes have been picked up and compiled.

Comment: Also looks like a delay between updating servlet jsp and server. All good now. Not instantaneous even on local box...thx!

Comment: @Paul It can't be; when `web.xml` is updated it requires a complete app restart.

Comment: No no. When updating the jsp and servlets. Taking some time(2 sec). So I thought nothing was showing up. I was hitting to quick the page.

Comment: @Paul Well, it has to recognize the file changed, then recompile the JSP, which while fast, isn't instantaneous.